# On WARC-Type of entries in StormCrawler WARC files

Tags: stormcrawler

Following an upgrade of our crawler from StormCrawler 1.8 to 1.14 we have noticed that response type of our WARC entries had changed from "WARC-Type: response" to "WARC-Type: resource".
Any suggestion on how to switch back to "WARC-Type: response"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing has changed in the [WARCRecordFormat](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/1640b05cd8b2ed3d4bcf7cfc0b73e4f89ab7093d/external/warc/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/warc/WARCRecordFormat.java#L310) between 1.8 and 1.14 - if there is a verbatim HTTP response header available, a response record is written. If there is no HTTP header, a [WARC resource](http://iipc.github.io/warc-specifications/specifications/warc-format/warc-1.1/#resource) record is used instead.

In order to store the HTTP headers, the following configuration is required:

```
http.store.headers: true

http.protocol.implementation: com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.protocol.okhttp.HttpProtocol
https.protocol.implementation: com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.protocol.okhttp.HttpProtocol
```

More information is found in the [README of the WARC module](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/warc/README.md).